# Checking multiple values in a SQL array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I need to check if one (or more) of several values is present in a SQL array.
In its simplest form it would look something like this:

```
SELECT
  (1, 7, 8) IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
FROM DUAL
```

Obviously this statement won't work. It only works if I check for just one value in the array. But I need to know if one (not all!) of the values I supply is present in the SQL array. The statement should return TRUE if one or more values are present in the array and FALSE if none is.

I realize I could just add several checks, like this:

```
SELECT
   1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
OR 7 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
OR 8 IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
FROM DUAL
```

My programming logic however supplies the values in array format "(1, 7, 8)" and the amount of values in this array differs every time i need to run the SQL statement. It would be very handy if I could somehow just paste this array into my existing SQL statement instead of rebuilding the SQL statement on every run, and create the "OR" statements for every value in the array.

Is there a way to do this? I'm using MySQL btw.

Thanx in advance, keep up the good programming!

Comment: Is it possible for your "programming logic" to pass a table since SQL works best with tables, not delimited lists?

Comment: how would this table look like?

if it's something like:
SELECT (1,7,8) FROM DUAL

then that would be possible, but I could just build that into the SQL statement. I still don't see how I could test the values to the SQL array.

Comment: In .net something like a `datatable` or an array.  A comma-separated list is not an array, its a string.

Comment: Why is it necessary to evaluate that in (My)SQL?

Comment: I understand that but I want to paste the values into an existing SQL statement so I convert the array to a comma-separated list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use REGEXP with comma separated strings. You'll have to convert the values first to strings.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT(",", "1, 7, 8", ",")," ", "")
       REGEXP CONCAT(",", REPLACE(REPLACE("1 ,2 , 3 , 4 ,5 " ," ", ""),",", ",|,"), ",")
FROM DUAL
```

Explanation:

- This works only with comma-separated *strings*, not lists as in your
  example.
- The statement removes any spaces from the strings.
- Commas are added at both ends of the strings to avoid partial matches.
- In the regex pattern all commas are replaced by comma + pipe-sign + comma, so it
  works as an OR , while avoiding partial matches.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a simple join creating a dynamic/temporary table and making a simple join with the other values?

```
create table a (
id int);

insert into a values (1),(7),(8);

create table b like a;

insert into b values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);


select a.* from a
inner join b
on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: I'm curious whether the query plan is the same for your answer and for `SELECT a.* from a where a.id IN (SELECT b.id FROM b)`. Do you think an `EXPLAIN` will reveal that those two queries are actually identical?

Comment: @ Kirk Olson. You're welcome. @ Chris Cunningham. I usually tend to avoid IN clause because AFAIK it's slower with mysql version < 5.5 but I'm not a sql guru about query optimization like Quassnoi and other SO users ;)

Comment: @nick rulez I'm hoping that Kirk will run the `EXPLAINS` for us and let us know. There's still time to become an expert!